# tar create rename directories

Tags: tar, freebsd

I have a directory named `dir` with files `file1` `file2` `file3` in it and I want to create a gzipped tar directory from it called `dir.tar.gz` but with the hierarchy as:

```
anotherdir/file1
anotherdir/file2
anotherdir/file3
```

There's always the option of writing a shell script to rename `dir` to `anotherdir` then tar it, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use a symlink and dereference during tarring.

```
$ mkdir dir && touch dir/file{1,2,3} && ln -sf dir anotherdir
$ tar -hcvpf a.tar anotherdir
anotherdir/
anotherdir/file1
anotherdir/file2
anotherdir/file3
$ tar -tf a.tar 
anotherdir/
anotherdir/file1
anotherdir/file2
anotherdir/file3
```

Comment: The problem is my setup is not typical and the directory anotherdir already exists. Is there no other way?

Comment: `anotherdir` can be in any directory. cd to /tmp first and then create the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a symlink and then force `tar` to follow it:

```
ln -s dir anotherdir
tar -czf dir.tar.gz -L anotherdir
```

Beware that will *also* follow any symlinks inside the tree.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work fine. Tar will not follow links, but the resulting tar will have additional ./ for the files (which I think is not a big deal).

```
mkdir dir another_dir && touch dir/file{1,2,3} another_dir/another_file{1,2,3}

tmp_dir=`mktemp -d /tmp/dXXXX` && ln -s `pwd`/dir $tmp_dir/another_dir && 
    tar -C $tmp_dir -cvf result.tar another_dir/. &&
    rm $tmp_dir/another_dir && rmdir $tmp_dir
```